# Partitioning on workstation

Tags: partitioning, windows-server-2012

I am using Win server 2012 as workstation and want to know how I can create a partition. I am worried about installation that I already have made. I am also worried if it will decrease my performance after doing it, because I have no prior experience with it.

I have 500 GB hard-disk and here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Can someone recommend a size and tell me about the pros and cons of creation another partition on my computer?

Comment: Your questions misses an essential detail: What do you need the second partition for?

Answer (score 2):

You can safely change partition sizes in Disk Management.  Right click on the C: partition and select "shrink."  From there, change it to the values you want.  After it is completed you can  create a new volume on the drive.   Obviously, if the data is important you should always make a backup before doing any major disk activity.  Although the method is safe, a power outage while rearranging the disk can cause data loss.

As for performance, you will see no loss.  This is because physically nothing has changed.  Since the partition is on the same drive, the disk controller and drive still has to do the same amount of work.

If you added a new physical drive, then the work can be divided across disk controllers and disk drives, giving you a performance increase.

Comment: In general, yes, but the performance isn't the same on the whole drive. If you force the page file into the slowest part of the drive, you might very well decrease the system's performance.

Comment: what if it was a SSD?  then perfomance wouldnt be affected at all.  Given general information, you can only give a general answer.

Comment: This doesn't apply to SSDs, but SSDs aren't HDDs.